# Java: Does try execute all lines, or jump to catch?

Tags: java, try-catch, order-of-execution

I was wondering about the execution path of a java try-catch statement, and couldn't find details on the following situation.

If I have a statement such as:

```
try {

  // Make a call that will throw an exception
  thisWillFail();

  // Other calls below:
  willThisExecute();

} catch (Exception exception) {
  // Catch the exception
}
```

Will the lines below thisWillFail() execute before moving to the catch, or will execution of the try statement jump to the catch as soon as an exception is thrown?

In other words, is it safe to assume that call 'b' following call 'a' will execute, provided call 'a' does not throw an exception in the try statement?

Thanks

Comment: What stops you from trying it out?

Comment: Nothing but time, but I thought it would be a useful question for others too, since I didn't find an answer easily.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NO, the lines below `thisWillFail()` will not execute. The execution would move to the catch block.

Comment: I chose your answer because it was straight and to the point, even though the other answers were correct and useful too.

Answer (score 4):

If any clause included in the try clause generates an error, the code in the catch clause (corresponding to that error - you can have multiple catch for a single try) will be executed. There is no way to know in advance if a particular clause will fail or not, only to try to recover after the error happens.

In other words as soon as an exception is thrown by the `thisWillFail()` function the catch clause will be executed and thereby bypassing the `willThisExecute()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just test this yourself?

Once an exception is thrown, the try block is abandoned and execution resumes at the `catch/finally` statements.

Answer (score 1):

It will not execute any further instruction in the that try block it will jump to the catch block and execute catch block.And after that it will execute finally(remember finally will be executed in every case whether there is any exception or not).To read further here is a good article line([[http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html]](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html%5d))

Answer (score -1):

in case of exception try block will execute all statements before exception statement and then control goes to catch block.